# Why should we set symbolic link when we build a library?

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

I have a question related to building a library in C++ for multiple platforms. I notice that many libraries expect a "symbolic link". With CMake, the symbolic link is done by the following codes:

```
set_target_properties({library_name}, PROPERTIES VERSION, ${library_string_version} SOVERSION {library_string_shortversion})
```

I cannot understand why symbolic link is necessary for a library. Moreover, it seems to me symbolic link is always related to the version of the library, and are there any relationships between them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using a symbolic link is that you can easily update the library, with a new version, maintaining a consistent name, while at the same time having the version in the library name accessible. So applications can always link against the same name if even if you update it. Only when they need a specific version, they can link to that instead.
Also it makes it easier to move it around if need be, because the application doesn't need to know where it comes from.

I often wish I had symbolic links in MS Windows as well, as it makes life much easier.

Comment: There are [NTFS Junctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point). [I use this](http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.com/2011/10/ssds-and-windows-users-directory.html) to point `C:\Users` to `D:\Users` where C: is my SSD and D: is my 1TB RAID array.

Comment: Thanks! I was not fully aware of that, even though I heard some bits about it, but never investigated it throughly. I always had the impression that it is rather complicated to set this up, but from your link it looks not worse then on a Unix environment.

Answer (score 2):

It allows for side-by-side versioning of the library.

```
libfoo.so -> libfoo.2.so
libfoo.1.so -> libfoo.1.23.so
libfoo.1.23.so
libfoo.2.so -> libfoo.2.1.so
libfoo.2.1.so
```

This way, `libfoo.so` is *always* the latest version.  If you know, (for compatibility reasons) that you need version 1 and not version 2, you can link against `libfoo.1.so`, and always have the latest v1 version.